# How typing objects inside a iterable?

Tags: python, typing

I want to type a list of objects in a function, but the list dont has a fixed length. For now, I type the list:

```
class MyModel:
    pass

def my_func(var: List):
    pass
```

But I want something like this:

```
class MyModel:
    pass

def my_func(var: List[MyModel, ...])
    pass
```

But this is not working. How do I do this?

Comment: Why not `List[MyModel]`? You don't have to provide the type of every single element in the list

Comment: Thank you. This will work. Something it is so obvious that I dont see the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want all list elements to be the same type, use `(var: List[MyModel])`
- If you need it to have multiple types inside, use [Unions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)
- If you don't know all types that will appear inside, just use `(var: List)`

Please also note, that according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

> The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.